# YouTube API - get monthly views from foreign channel

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I try finding a way to get the viewcount of the last 6 months of any given YouTube channel. The YouTube analytics API is not helpful, cause it only allows for channels I own - the YouTube data API only returns the total view count of the channel lifetime.

Is there a way I can get the view count a channel has made on a monthly basis via the API? Scraping socialblade is my second option, but I'd rather use the Google Api.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: AFAIK you can't request to YouTube Data API v3 data from the past. However by regularly retrieving the data from YouTube you will be able in the future to get these statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to have to do it like socalblade probably does.

Just scan each channel you want to check every month.

YouTube analytics api only stores data for three months I think and you have to be authorized as you mentioned.

The YouTube data api doesn't store data by date its not intended for analytics.

I set up a system for a client a while back that just poles a few channels every day to get stats for them.  Its not optimal but it works.